# Multiplying elements from tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply elements in a tuple and store them into a list currently my output is

```
(122034, 130546, 130110)
(122034, 130546, 121657)
(122034, 130546, 121109)
(122034, 130110, 121657)
(122034, 130110, 121109)
(122034, 121657, 121109)
(130546, 130110, 121657)
(130546, 130110, 121109)
(130546, 121657, 121109)
(130110, 121657, 121109)
```

What I want is :

```
list = [2072788988882040,1938945758213904,...]
```

So is there a way to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-multiply-numbers-list-3-different-ways/

Comment: What do you figure are the steps to solving the problem? What part don't you know how to do yourself? What happened when you tried to write the code? What code did you write, and what went wrong? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Kindly tell us where do you feel the difficulty, in finding the solution to it, And what did u try ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't exactly know the structure of your input but I guess this is what you wanted. Correct me if I didn't understand your query.

```py
all_elements = [(122034, 130546, 130110),
(122034, 130546, 121657),
(122034, 130546, 121109),
(122034, 130110, 121657),
(122034, 130110, 121109),
(122034, 121657, 121109),
(130546, 130110, 121657),
(130546, 130110, 121109),
(130546, 121657, 121109),
(130110, 121657, 121109)]

op_list = [i[0]*i[1]*i[2] for i in all_elements]

print(*op_list)
```

gives you the output as

```py
2072788988882040 1938123818464548 1929393602755476 1931650835877180 1922949777507660 1798019376544842 2066385515679420 2057077549326540 1923433121346698 1917009203027430
```